# Why closing an Input Stream closes the associated File Descriptor as well, even the File Descriptor is shared among multiple streams ?

Tags: java, file-descriptor

I was just going through the implementation of [FileInputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileInputStream.java#FileInputStream.close%28%29) and confused with the close method implementation, which is as given below,

```
public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (closeLock) {
            if (closed) {
                return;
            }
            closed = true;
        }
        if (channel != null) {
           channel.close();
        }

        fd.closeAll(new Closeable() {
            public void More ...close() throws IOException {
               close0();
           }
        });
}
```

This internally calls `closeAll` on [FileDescriptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileDescriptor.java#FileDescriptor.closeAll%28java.io.Closeable%29), which releases all the Closables (not only the particular instance which calls the close). So a close call on an Input Stream closes all the streams share that FileDescriptor.

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("Some file");
    BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    FileDescriptor fd = is.getFD();

    FileInputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(fd);
    BufferedInputStream br1 = new BufferedInputStream(is1);

    is.close();
    System.out.println(is1.read());
```

In the above example `FileDescriptor` `fd` is shared among streams `is` and `is1`. A close call on `is` closes `is1` as well (basically `fd` is closed/released)

My question is, FileInputStream has a flag to indicated its closed or not, but still why its closing the FileDescriptor when other active streams are pointing to it, making all of them fail/invalid, instead of just closing the calling instance and close the FileDescriptor when no other streams are pointing to it?

Comment: Frankly, I think it's because `FileDescriptor`s aren't supposed to be reused like you're using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open `FileInputStreams` from a `File` object instead of a `FileDescriptor` you'll get the behavior you expect:

```
File f = new File( ... );
InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream( f );
InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream( f );
```

You'll see in the [FileInputStream( File )](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileInputStream.java#FileInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%29) constructor source that this creates a new `FileDescriptor` for each `FileInputStream` instead of sharing one passed in, as happens in the [FileInputStream( FileDescriptor )](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileInputStream.java#FileInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29) constructor.

From the [javadoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileDescriptor.java#FileDescriptor), FileDescriptor wraps the underlying native OS structure representing an open file handle.

The whole purpose of `InputStream.close()` is to clean up those native resources. So if two InputStreams are sharing the native file handle, when one gets closed the other is going to be affected as well.

In the alternative example that I provided above, two independent file handles are created at the OS / native level, so they can be closed independently.

Comment: Yes, if we open files explicitly this issues doesn't happen. But I am confused, why a close call releases/closes all the streams using it, when file descriptors are shared among those, instead of just closing that once instance. Just wonder is there any specific reason behind that ?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to address that. It's because of what FileDescriptor represents: the OS/native file handle. So your two InputStreams are sharing this OS level / native connection to the file.

If you look at the JavaDoc for [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close--) you'll see that **what is does** is close operating system resources.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your prompt help.